# How do I fix these incompatible data types?

Tags: java

I'm adding two random numbers (generated by my program). The operation variable is a String that the user inputs what type of math problem they wish to have(+,-, or *). This is only one section of my full program.

```
public static double getCorrectAnswer(int operand1, int operand2, String operation){
    double correctResponse;
    correctResponse =(operand1 + (operation) + operand2);

    return correctResponse;
}
```

Comment: use a switch statement (or if/else block) on the operation and do the appropriate math operation

Answer (score 3):

Use `if`:

```
if (operand.equals("+")) {
    ...
}
else if (operand.equals("*")) {
    ...
}
...
```

You can also use a switch.

Note that you should return an int, since adding and multiplying integers will return an integer.

Comment: Or a long if the multiplied integers become quite big :)

Comment: It will return a long only if at least one of the operands is promoted to long. otherwise, it will overflow, but still return an (incorrect) int.

Comment: I realize that it will return an int, but the result might be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This may be too much for you but you could have a look at a formal language parser such as [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)